# Material UI React change hover border color of MuiOutlinedInput

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't change border color hover state of MuiOutlinedInput

Screenshot:

[image: materialui]

test is not relevant on picture element is activated on MuiOutlinedInput-root and not base

I tried to change it with theme and styles and still not working

Comment: As a quick fix, try adding `!important` at the end of your custom style.

Comment: Still same, not working, I tried every possible class of input and still hover color doesn't change

Comment: Did you do: `border-color: red !important;`

Comment: Could it be some other property for shade/shadow of input?

Comment: Yes I did something overrides it and I tried to override it with theme everything else works except this input hover border color even color inside changes when it's hover over

Comment: I noticed possible bug, when I select 'MuiInputBase-root' class and add hover it adds same hover class but doesn't change but selecting 'MuiOutlinedInput-root' class and adding hover border color changes